# Connecting Cypress to SQL Server Database using Tedious

Tags: sql-server, database, cypress, ui-automation, tedious

I'm trying to connect Cypress with a SQL Server database, I installed Tedious in the project, I've already done all the necessary settings (plugins/index.js, support/commands.js & cypress.json), but the task that is executing the query returns timeout (as you can see in the image below) every time.

[image: cypress printscreen]

cypress.json

```
{
    "env": {
        "db": {
            "server": "server\\devtransaction",
            "authentication": {
                "type": "default",
                "options": {
                    "username": "username",
                    "password": "password"
                }
            },
            "options": {
                "port": 3300,
                "database": "database",
                "encrypt": true,
                "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion": true,
                "trustServerCertificate": true,
                "validateBulkLoadParameters": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

plugins/index.js

```
module.exports = (on, config) =\> {
on('task', {
sqlServer: (sql) =\> {
return execSQL(sql, config.env.db);
},
});

    return config;

};

const tedious = require('tedious');
function execSQL(sql, config) {
const conn = new tedious.Connection(config);
return new Promise((res, rej) =\> {
conn.on('connect', (err) =\> {
if (err) {
rej(err);
}

            const request = new tedious.Request(sql, function (err, rowCount, rows) {
                return err ? rej(err) : res(rows);
            });
    
            conn.execSQL(request);
        });
    });

}
```

support/commands.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('sqlServer', (query) =\> {
if (!query) {
throw new Error('Query must be set');
}

    cy.task('sqlServer', query).then((response) => {
        let result = [];
    
        const flatten = (r) =>
            Array.isArray(r) && r.length === 1 ? flatten(r[0]) : r;
    
        if (response) {
            for (let i in response) {
                result[i] = [];
                for (let c in response[i]) {
                    result[i][c] = response[i][c].value;
                }
            }
            result = flatten(result);
        } else {
            result = response;
        }
    
        return result;
    });

});
```

And I'm using it like this, on my spec:

```
cy.sqlServer(
`delete from TABLE where NR_CNPJ=${cnpj}`
).then((res) => cy.log(res));
```

But I get an error:

> cy.task('sqlServer') timed out after waiting 60000ms.

and nothing happens!

I would expect a successful SQL Server database connection, so I can setup my tests.

Comment: Specify an instance name `\\devtransaction` or a port number `3300`, but not both. Also, port 3300 would be unsual for an SQL Server, it's almost the 3306 that MySQL uses.

Comment: That didn't work, I've tried it before. I'll see with the development team next week if they can shed some light on it.

Comment: I'd start by confirming the port number - the default port for SQL Server is 1433. Then start confirming connectivity for tcp/1433 access (or whatever port it actually uses) through any firewalls sitting between Cypress and SQL Server, including Windows Firewall on the SQL Server itself (assuming it's hosted on Windows).

Comment: The problem seems to be with the escaped backslash in the cypress.json for the server "server\\devtransaction", when creating the connection with the bank ```const conn = new tedious.Connection(config);``` it can't even reach the sql server database because of the wrong server address. I couldn't find a solution to that yet.

Comment: If you actually need to use the devtransaction instance name then there are other network requirements to make it work: 1) the SQL Browser service on the target server must be running; 2) Windows Firewall on the target server must allow incoming access to udp/1434; 3) any intermediate network firewalls must allow incoming access to udp/1434; 4) whichever TCP port the instance is listening on must also be accessible via Windows Firewall and any intermediate network firewalls. It's usually easier to connect using the port number if you know the port number in advance.